# Create new ID3 tag using python and eyed3

Tags: python, eyed3

I have a bunch of mp3 files that have no ID3 tag at all. I am trying to use eyed3 to add an ID3 tag to the files, but cannot figure out what method to use. Here is my code:

```
import eyed3

file = eyed3.load("test.mp3")
file.tag.artist = u"MP3 Artist"
```

I get the following error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'artist'"

I have figured out that it is because the MP3 file doesn't have any ID3 tag at all. If I do this using other MP3 files that already have tags, it works fine. How do I attach a new ID3 tag to the MP3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to run [initTag](http://eyed3.nicfit.net/api/eyed3.id3.html?highlight=save#eyed3.id3.TagFile.initTag) first to initialize the tag:

```
import eyed3

file = eyed3.load("test.mp3")
file.initTag()
file.tag.artist = u"MP3 Artist"
```

Comment: Thank you! I have looked all over, and could not figure that out. I appreciate it.