# ID3 tags not displaying in Windows file properties

Tags: python, windows, mp3, id3, eyed3

I am using eyeD3 within Python 3.6 to edit the ID3 tag of an mp3 file.

I can confirm within the Python console that my ID3 tag edits are taking effect. However, when viewing the file properties within Windows, none of the changes are shown in the metadata.

Here is the sample code which runs without error:

```
import eyed3

filename = 'test.mp3'

audiofile = eyed3.load(filename)
audiofile.tag.Album = u"Best Album Ever"
audiofile.tag.save()

print(audiofile.tag.album)
```

The above code edits the Album to "Best Album Ever". I have confirmed that the code takes effect by using the last line once again:

```
print(audiofile.tag.album)
```

The console properly prints "Best Album Ever". Yet when I look at the metadata in Windows, no changes are found.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I found a solution after some additional searching here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495351/eyed3-package-for-python-not-properly-setting-id3-metadata

The issue is that Windows uses an older version of ID3 and this must be specified when saving the tags with eyeD3.

Comment: Note that my above posted solution was only partially successful. In general the documentation for ID3v1 vs ID3v2 tags and how they are represented in Windows is very lacking. Only some tags seem to translate and not always as expected.