# Custom key in mp3 file metadata

Tags: python, id3

I am trying to hash some mp3 files and store that hash value in the mp3's metadata. Is there a way that I can add a custom key/tag in the metadata other than the traditional tags of `['author', 'album', 'date']`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create new ID3 tag using python and eyed3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326789/create-new-id3-tag-using-python-and-eyed3)

Comment: I was able to create a new tag using the code from the linked duplicate, and changing `file.tag.artist = u"MP3 Artist"` line to `file.tag.hash = u"<hash_value>"`

Comment: @downshift when I did `initTag()`, it wipes my existing tags, is there a way to do it without wiping my initial tags?

Comment: My apologies, appears the `initTag()` line is not required. Remove that line and it should keep the current tags' info.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, [eyeD3](http://eyed3.nicfit.net) can do this. Custom key/tag works the same the other predefined key/tags. Choose a key/tag name, reference and assign it to your value.

```
import eyed3

audiofile = eyed3.load('audio_file.mp3')
# add your hash key/tag/value

audiofile.tag.hash = u"ec457d0a974c48d5685a7efa03d137dc8bbde7e3" # example value
print audiofile.tag.hash # ec457d0a974c48d5685a7efa03d137dc8bbde7e3
```

Confirm other metadata is intact:

```
print audiofile.tag.artist # e.g. Henry Reed
```

Hope this helps.